# How to set scheduled task?

Tags: task, wso2

Before this I asked a question. My service conifg is :

```xml
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="UnpayBilling_Task"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <class name="com.coship.mediator.UnpayBillingMediator"></class>
         <log level="full" />
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" />
         <send />
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://172.21.13.153:18080/aaa/services/receiveMsg" />
      </endpoint>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

I write a extension mediator `UnpayBillingMediator` deal files. The class returns file name and send request to service `http://172.21.13.153:18080/aaa/services/receiveMsg`. The service no input message. I want service running every day at 13:30. I tried add New Scheduled Task. 
`soapAction:urn:mediate,to:http://localhost:8280/services/UnpayBilling?wsdl, Cron: 30 13 * * *.` But it can not work? Anyone can tell me how to set this Scheduled Task?

```
SimpleQuartz Server name not in pinned servers list. Not starting Task
```

I also do not know how to set "pinned servers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain how the default message injector task works in WSO2 ESB.

It basically creates the message with the given properties (ex : message payload , to address etc ) and Inject it to the main sequence in configured intervals.

So in your case you will have to change your main sequence in a such a way that it will filter messages coming with given `To` address or your specific message body and send it forward.

The easiest thing to do is just change the default filter that is in WSO2ESB main sequence so that it will filter your to address and send it to backend service.

ex : change the filter as:

```xml
<filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd
        xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
        source="get-property('To')"
        regex="http://localhost:8280/services/UnpayBilling.*" >
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's very kind of you. But I do not understand you very well. Can you tell me how to set this service to a scheduled task? My config is also showing above. Maybe you can have a try. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Please Look at the following ESB Configuration

Which got a Proxy named Test and a Task named MyTask where when MyTask inject message to the main sequence, We filter the "To" property and if its is the value we set from Task then we send it to the proxy service.

Config :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry">
        <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
    </registry>
    <proxy name="Test" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="IN" value="IN"/>
                </log>
                <drop/>
            </inSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
    <sequence name="fault">
        <log level="full">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
            <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
        </log>
        <drop/>
    </sequence>
    <sequence name="main">
        <in>
            <filter xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="get-property('To')" regex="http://localhost:8280/services/Test">
                <then>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint>
                            <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/Test"/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </then>
                <else/>
            </filter>
        </in>
        <out>
            <drop/>
        </out>
        <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
    </sequence>
    <task name="MyTask" class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz">
        <trigger count="1" interval="4"/>
        <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="to" value="http://localhost:8280/services/Test"/>
        <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
            <msg xmlns="">FROM_TASK</msg>
        </property>
    </task>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can added a scheduled task simple Trigger Type. I use Cron Trigger Type it says "Error editing a task : Error starting up Scheduler : Error setting cron expression : Unexpected end of expression.30 13 * * *". I tried several times. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue in your cron expression. 
Please reffer to http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger